# How to play the song one by one retrieve from the database?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I like to play songs one by one.I returned the array of the songs name and pass to my view.Following is my view.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="audio-name">



    <?php foreach ($view as $row) :?>

        <?php echo $row->audio;?>






    </div>



        <center>
            <audio controls>
                    <source src="<?php echo base_url();?>musics/<?php echo $row->audio;?>"  type="audio/mp3">

            </audio>
        </center>
        <center><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/audio/showaudio" class='back'>Back to All song list</a></center>
        <?php endforeach;?>

    </div>
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

all song player appear at once.How can i fix it.Please help me.